# Python clang bindings: recognize sizeof node and get the type

Tags: python, clang, sizeof

I'm using the libclang python bindings on some C code. I can't figure out how to get information about `sizeof` nodes. I can't find any relevant documentation. Experimentally:

- `sizeof` nodes have the kind `CursorKind.CXX_UNARY_EXPR`.
- `sizeof(type)` has no child. `sizeof expression` has one child which is `expression`.

Makes sense so far, but then what? How do I distinguish `sizeof` from other unary expressions? How do I obtain the type in `sizeof(type)`?

I'm using the libclang 10.0.0 and the corresponding Python bindings as shipped in Ubuntu 18.04 (`python3-clang-10`).

Here's a small C source file `foo.c` to experiment with:

```c
#include <stddef.h>
size_t foo(void) {
    return sizeof(unsigned short) + sizeof 1234;
}
```

A dump from the Clang AST parser shows all the information I'd expect.

```
$ clang -Xclang -ast-dump -fsyntax-only foo.c | tail -n 5
    `-ReturnStmt 0x97ad48 <line:3:5, col:44>
      `-BinaryOperator 0x97ad28 <col:12, col:44> 'unsigned long' '+'
        |-UnaryExprOrTypeTraitExpr 0x97acc8 <col:12, col:33> 'unsigned long' sizeof 'unsigned short'
        `-UnaryExprOrTypeTraitExpr 0x97ad08 <col:37, col:44> 'unsigned long' sizeof
          `-IntegerLiteral 0x97ace8 <col:44> 'int' 1234
```

And here's the Python code I used to explore the Python data structure.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import clang.cindex
from clang.cindex import CursorKind

def explore_attrs(node):
    for attr in sorted(dir(node)):
        try:
            value = getattr(node, attr)
        except AssertionError as e: # Skip attributes whose accessor only works with specific kinds
            continue
        if callable(value): continue
        if value is None: continue
        print(attr, repr(value))

def explore(node):
    """Print information about an AST node."""
    print('Children:', [(child.kind, child.spelling) for child in node.get_children()])
    print('Arguments:', list(node.get_arguments()))
    print('Definition:', node.get_definition())
    explore_attrs(node)

def main():
    index = clang.cindex.Index.create()
    tu = index.parse('foo.c')
    for node in tu.cursor.walk_preorder():
        if node.kind == CursorKind.RETURN_STMT:
            children = list(node.get_children())
            # Expect sizeof(...) + sizeof(...)
            assert children[0].kind == CursorKind.BINARY_OPERATOR
            lhs, rhs = children[0].get_children()
            explore(lhs)
            print()
            explore(rhs)

main()
```